# Print a square pattern full of "#" using two while loops

Tags: c, while-loop

Given an input, I want to print a square like this:

```
Enter number: 5
#####
#####
#####
#####
#####
```

My attempt:

```
int n;
int col=0;
int row=0;
//user input blah blah

    while  (col < n) {
        while (row < n) {
            printf("#");
            row++;
        }
        col++;
        printf("\n");
    }
```

But it isn't printing what I'm expecting... can anyone fix this?

EDIT: The actual output looks like this (followed by 4 \n characters, SO doesn't seem to display it).

```
#####
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while  (col < n) {
    while (row < n) {
        printf("#");
        row++;
    }
    col++;
    printf("\n");
    row = 0; // <<< THIS HELPS
}
```

Comment: Nice, simple and fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[typo.pl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509059/print-a-square-full-of-using-two-while-loops/5509092#5509092) solves the immediate problem, but I'd like to point out a couple things:

1. this is the kind of loop control construct that `for` loops are designed for.  The initialization and increment are packaged up in the loop control instead of being scattered wherever you (or that other guy) might decide to put it.
2. you've switched the logic for `row` control and `col` control.  That doesn't matter here since you have the same number of each. But when it's time to add rectangle support, it's going to cause a moment of confusion for someone. And if it's homework, it'll probably mean a couple points off.

So:

```
for (row = 0; row < n; ++row) {
    for (col = 0; col < n; ++col) {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `row` after the first while loop, otherwise it'll already be `n`.

Comment: What about nesting the `col` in `row` instead of `row` in `col`? I'll try it out...

Comment: @meiryo: Yes, technically that would be more correct as the inner loop is printing rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for printing [square pattern in C](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/07/square-star-pattern-in-c.html) filled with "#"

```
i=1;
while(i<=n)
{
    j=1;
    while(j<=n)
    {
        printf("#");
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simpler? Math expressions are often more precise than controls.

```
In [1]: n = 5

In [2]: s = ('#'*n+'\n')*n

In [3]: print(s)
#####
#####
#####
#####
#####
```